# Entity is not being created on database when JoinColumn annotation is added

Tags: spring, hibernate, one-to-many, joincolumn

I have this model class:

```
public class Usuario {
...
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  private List<org.loja.model.credencial.Credencial> credenciais;
...
}
```

If I add this annotation to this attribute:

```
@JoinColumn(unique=false)
```

causes the table `usuario_credenciais` not being created on database (it is when the annotation is omitted, but causes problems during runtime due to the uniqueness situation).

What I can do to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that changing the OneToMany annotation to ManyToOne, getting this:

```
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name="usuario_credenciais", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="usuario_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="credencial_id")})
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  private List<org.loja.model.credencial.Credencial> credenciais;
```

Now the table is created on the database, and the application allows multiple users have the same credentials.